# Sandwich property of the line integral by arclength

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, definite-integrals

Let $L\subset\mathbb R^2$ be a continuous smooth simple line given by $L = \{(\phi_1(t), \phi_2(t)): t\in [\alpha,\beta]\subset\mathbb R\}$.

Let $T\in\mathfrak T$ be a partition of $[\alpha,\beta]$, so the line $L$ gets 'chopped' into arcs $$L = X_0X_1\cup X_1X_2\cup\ldots\cup X_{n-1}X_n $$
Let $f,g,h:L\to\mathbb R$ be some functions. Denote
$$\sigma (T) = \sum_{j=1}^n f(Q_j)s_j$$
where $Q_j\in X_{j-1}X_j$ is an arbitrary point on the sub-arc and $s_j$ denotes the length of $X_{j-1}X_j$.

Denote by $\lambda (T)$ the maximal length of a subinterval in $T$. Define
$$\exists \lim_{\lambda (T)\to 0}\sigma (T)\Longrightarrow \lim_{\lambda (T)\to 0}\sigma (T) = \int _Lf\mbox{d} s $$

> Let $f\leq h\leq g$ and $\int_Lf = \int_Lg =: A$. Show that $\exists \int_Lh=A$.

**Attempt**
The integrability def. is equivalent to $$\forall\varepsilon >0,\exists\delta >0; \forall T\in\mathfrak T\left (\lambda (T)<\delta\Longrightarrow \left\lvert \sigma (T)-A \right\rvert <\varepsilon \right ) $$

The thing I don't understand is this; are the points $Q_j$ in the subarcs picked the same when we compute $\sigma (T)$ for $f,g,h$? If so then it would be trivial that $$\sigma _f(T)\leq \sigma _h (T)\leq \sigma _g(T) $$
Would then have
$$-\varepsilon < \sigma _f(T)-A\leq \sigma _h(T)-A\leq \sigma _g(T)-A <\varepsilon $$

If not, though, then we can't guarantee $\sigma _f (T)\leq \sigma _h(T)$, can we? Or am I going about this in a wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find $\delta_1$ for $f$ and $\delta_2$ for $g$ and take $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$. Then you consider a partition $T_0$ for $h$ with $\lambda(T_0)<\delta$ and consider arbitrary points $P_j\in X_{j-1}X_j$. In the definition of limit for $f$ and $g$,  you can take any partition $T$ as long as $\lambda_i(T)\le \delta_i$ and any choice of points $Q_j$ in the subintervals of $T$, so the partition $T_0$ and this particular choice of points $P_j$ is admissible. And then you can continue as in your proof.
So yes you can take the same points for all three functions, but only because you know that for two of them the limit exists. Hope this make sense. 
Think about the proof of the squeeze theorem. Same principle.